# ffmpeg. Converting through rawbitstream results to noise

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, conversion, raw

I tried consequentially commands below. On output I'm getting video with a mess (even.mp4).

```
ffmpeg -i in.MOV -an -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p rawbitstream.yuv

ffmpeg -r 2 -s 640x480 -i rawbitstream.yuv -vf select="not(mod(n-1\,2))" -c:v rawvideo -r 1 -format rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -an even.yuv

ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 640x480 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i even.yuv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 even.mp4
```

[image]

Here is [full log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SQEPPZGB4ogf6cbczejbiyTdwK-1twfm).
Video files are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YfIwWo4FloOONNA8Fw05czAmWg3K__ei).

Comment: Share full log of commands

Comment: @Gyan see above.

Comment: How are you playing the output? Can you share the input?

Comment: @Gyan See the link above. Before I tried to play it with VLC (mess), but it worked in Parole Media Player.

Comment: So, the issue is with the profile. Do you need lossless?

Comment: @Gyan I would like do not lose quality of original video.

Comment: Lossless is unnecessary and most players can't play it.

Comment: @Gyan got it, could you provide answer with edited command(s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.MOV -an -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p rawbitstream.yuv

ffmpeg -s 640x480 -i rawbitstream.yuv -vf select="not(mod(n+1\,2))" -c:v rawvideo -vsync 0 -an even.yuv

ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i even.yuv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile:v high -qp 1 even.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like also to understand what is -qp and how it works. Hard to find info about it.

Comment: Quantization parameter. It controls how the raw coefficients - the error residuals - are transformed. You need to wade into DSP for the details - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(image_processing)